# grunt-contrib-copy task is not copying

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am writing grunt-contrib-copy task to copy from source to dest. But no files are copied. Even there are no errors. I am not able to understand what is happening.

```
 copy:{
        index: {
            files: [
                {
                    src: '<%= devDir %>/index.html',
                    dest: '<%= buildDir %>/index.html',
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                }
            ]
        }
 }
```

<%= devDir %> is defined to correct folder and <%= buildDir %> is also defined.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving wrong source path. Then grunt-contrib-copy will just return without error.

Always the path is reference from node-module where these grunt utils are installed.